# Vue.js error using vue-plotly : fullLayout is undefined

Tags: vue.js

I'm using vue-plotly for simple plots but I get a recurrent error in console :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: fullLayout is undefined
    emitAfterPlot vue-plotly.umd.js:140916
    plot vue-plotly.umd.js:140908
```

I've managed to reduce my component to a minimal example to help you reproduce the error and hopefully guide me through the resolution of this issue.

Here is my component MyPlot.vue:

```js
<template>
   <v-container>
      <Plotly 
          v-if='!loading'
          :data.sync="data"
          :layout="layout"
      ></Plotly>
      <div 
          v-else
          class="text-center"
      >
        <v-progress-circular
          indeterminate
          color="primary"
        ></v-progress-circular>
      </div>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { Plotly } from 'vue-plotly'

export default {
  components: {
    Plotly
  },
  data () {
      return {
        data: [],
        layout:{
            title: "My graph",
            showlegend: true,
        },
        loading:false
      }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.loading = true;
    this.loadData().then(data => {
      this.data = Object.seal(data);
      this.loading = false;
    });
  },
  methods: {
      loadData () {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          let data = [{
            x: [1,2,3,4],
            y: [10,15,13,17],
            type:"scatter"
          }];
          resolve(data);
        });
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

The mounting part may be overkill but this is relevant to my use case as I call my Vuex store and do some processing before plotting data.
It looks like the problem comes from the combination of the `v-if/v-else` template, and the way I load my data using promise. Indeed, removing one part or the other seems to work.

What vue-plotly is complaining about ? Sorry if this is a rookie error, I'm still learning vuejs. I posted a similar issue on the vue-plotly github repo, but it may be rather related to vuejs only.

Any ideas to solve/investigate this error ?

Comment: there is'nt container in template,  in vue js must single root element

you can find more info here; 
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element

Comment: @Ademyalçın My bad, I missed the root tag when I wrote the question but I do have it in my actual code. I edited my question.

Comment: I think the error is in the way you're handling the promises. Cause when I assign data value directly is works fine. Please refer docs to check on how Promises work

Comment: @beingyogi I know this has something to do with the way I handle my promise as I stated in my question. Could you elaborate a bit on what could be the origin of the error ? Because my use of Promise seems to be a rather simple use case if I look at the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise. And keeping the Promise while removing the v-if/v-else condition works as well which confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing this in mounted

```
    this.loading = true;
    this.loadData()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("result: ", result);
        this.data = result;
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log("error: ", error));
    this.loading = false;
```

I tried this on my system and it worked.

Comment: Can you explain what is causing the problem ? Because having `this.loading = false` outside the then block means loading variable will be updated before the promise result is handled, right ?